# Using a view from Storyboard to use its frame for another view that is set programatically

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, frame

I have a view that I must set programatically, I name it progView. 
I want to have its frame defined intuitively in storyboard. I thought of a work around - I will use a plain view, that I name storyView, I make an outlet to the ViewController and do something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var storyView: UIView!
```

and in viewDidLoad:

```
let progView = ProgView(frame: storyView.frame)
```

This results in progView not fitting the storyView.
I tried this as well:

```
let progView = ProgView(frame: storyView.bounds)
```

But that results worse.
Is there a way to easily fit a view to be exactly like another view?

Please tell in the comments if my question misses information and I will try my best to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try calling `let progView = ProgView(frame: storyView.frame)` inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, because inside `viewDidLoad` the view is not layouted yet

```
private var didLayoutSubview = false //to call this once, because theoretically viewDidLayoutSubviews can be called multiple times
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if !self.didLayoutSubiviews {
        self.didLayoutSubiviews = true
        let progView = ProgView(frame: storyView.frame)
    }
}
```